# Breaking up double integrals.

Tags: calculus

Evaluate
$$\iint_R (x^2y)dA$$

where $R$ is the region bounded by the graph of $y=x^2+x, y=x^2-x ,y=2$

Could I break the double integral into two parts as such

$$∬_R (x^2y)dA= \int_{-1}^0\int_{x^2-x}^2 (x^2y)dydx+\int_0^1\int_{x^2+x}^2 (x^2y)dyda$$

Can I do this? and if anyone would be kind to check I got  $∬_R (x^2y)dA=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to plot the region:

[image: region]

I'm not sure that your splitting will work.  Rather, the best thing to do is to integrate over $y \in [0,2]$; to do this, we must solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.  Note that the region is symmetric in $x$, so we really need only solve one equation:

$$x^2\pm x-y=0 \implies x = \pm\frac{\sqrt{1+4 y}-1}{2}$$

The double integral over $R$ is then

$$2 \int_0^2 dy \, y \: \int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{1+4 y}-1}{2}} dx \, x^2$$

Note that I exploited the evenness in $x$ to make the lower limit equal to $0$.  This then reduces to a single integral:

$$\frac{1}{12} \int_0^2 dy \, y [\sqrt{1+4 y}-1]^3$$

Perhaps you can take it from here.  I get $23/35$ for the answer.

Comment: I had a feeling I was wrong thanks for your help Ron!

Comment: @Andy: you're welcome.  If this or any other solution is useful to you, please remember to click the checkmark to accept the solution.

Comment: Ron I"m having trouble taking the integrate  $dy$ I was thinking about taking the LN but that would be too crazy.

Comment: @Andy: expand the cubic and substitute $u=1+4 y$ for each term.  The integrals become simple, but there will be a bunch of them, so the challenge is keeping track.

Comment: Wow @Ron: that was so crazy I had to do it four times to get it right .